# Can I run AWS Ethereum Preview with t2.micro

Tags: amazon-managed-blockchain

I am testing the creation of an AWS Ethereum network and when I create it with t2.micro, the following resources get stuck with status CREATE_IN_PROGRESS

EthereumMinerService
EthereumECSStack
EthereumCommonStack

I have been able to successfully get it running once with t2.small, if I remember correctly. Is it not possible to run with t2.micro?

Answer (score 1):

I work for AWS at a Blockchain Specialist capacity and I'm glad to help you here.

In February 2021 AWS launched a fully managed service for Ethereum nodes: Amazon Managed Blockchain. It offers a quick way to deploy Ethereum nodes.

https://aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/